# SQL подсчет непрерывного присутствия/отсутсвия

Tags: sql, frame

Есть таблица присутствия/отсутствия сотрудника в рабочий день офиса в виде:

[image: |user_id|user_position|date_position| |. 1 |. 1 |01.01.2019 | |. 1 |. 1 |02.01.2019 | |. 1 |. 2 |03.01.2019 | |. 1 |. 2 |04.01.2019 | |. 1 |. 1 |05.01.2019 |]

user_position 1 - присутсвовал, 2 - отсутствовал

Запросом нужно вывести дату начала вхождения в позицию position_start и дату окончания вхождения в позицию position_end  по каждому сотруднику и в разрезе user_position. То что должно получиться
[image: результат]

Пробовал использовать Rank чтобы разбить на неповторяющиеся периоды, но результат не совсем тот который нужен

```sql
select *,
    dense_rank() over(partition by user_id order by date_period) as rank
from User_p
```

Comment: @ Валерий К , здесь принято код и данные представлять в виде текста, а не картинкой и если ответ соответствует вашим ожиданиям отметьте его решением. Спасибо.

Answer (score 3):

Создадим следующую таблицу с нашими исходными данными

```
CREATE TABLE your_table_name (
    user_id NUMBER,
    user_position NUMBER,
    date_position DATE
);
```

Вставим данные:

```
INSERT ALL
    INTO your_table_name (user_id, user_position, date_position) VALUES (1, 1, TO_DATE('01.01.2019', 'DD.MM.YYYY'))
    INTO your_table_name (user_id, user_position, date_position) VALUES (1, 1, TO_DATE('02.01.2019', 'DD.MM.YYYY'))
    INTO your_table_name (user_id, user_position, date_position) VALUES (1, 2, TO_DATE('03.01.2019', 'DD.MM.YYYY'))
    INTO your_table_name (user_id, user_position, date_position) VALUES (1, 2, TO_DATE('04.01.2019', 'DD.MM.YYYY'))
    INTO your_table_name (user_id, user_position, date_position) VALUES (1, 1, TO_DATE('05.01.2019', 'DD.MM.YYYY'))
    INTO your_table_name (user_id, user_position, date_position) VALUES (1, 1, TO_DATE('06.01.2019', 'DD.MM.YYYY'))
    INTO your_table_name (user_id, user_position, date_position) VALUES (2, 1, TO_DATE('01.01.2019', 'DD.MM.YYYY'))
    INTO your_table_name (user_id, user_position, date_position) VALUES (2, 1, TO_DATE('02.01.2019', 'DD.MM.YYYY'))
    INTO your_table_name (user_id, user_position, date_position) VALUES (2, 1, TO_DATE('03.01.2019', 'DD.MM.YYYY'))
    INTO your_table_name (user_id, user_position, date_position) VALUES (2, 2, TO_DATE('04.01.2019', 'DD.MM.YYYY'))
    INTO your_table_name (user_id, user_position, date_position) VALUES (2, 2, TO_DATE('05.01.2019', 'DD.MM.YYYY'))
    INTO your_table_name (user_id, user_position, date_position) VALUES (2, 2, TO_DATE('08.01.2019', 'DD.MM.YYYY'))
    INTO your_table_name (user_id, user_position, date_position) VALUES (2, 2, TO_DATE('10.01.2019', 'DD.MM.YYYY'))
SELECT * FROM DUAL;
```

Работаю с Oracle, поэтому запрос будет с использованием его функционала. В подзапросе используем оконную функцию `row_number()` чтобы пронумеровать строки в каждой группе по `user_id` и `user_position`, а затем вычеслим разницу между этой нумерацией по `user_id` без учёта `user_position`. Так мы создадим группы для агрегации. Сгруппируем в последсвтии результаты по данному аргументу агреации, чтобы получить начальную и конечную даты. Затем выведем.

```
SELECT user_id, user_position, MIN(date_position) AS date_start, MAX(date_position) AS date_end
FROM (
    SELECT user_id, user_position, date_position,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY date_position) -
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY user_id, user_position ORDER BY date_position) AS grp
    FROM your_table_name
)
GROUP BY user_id, user_position, grp
ORDER BY user_id, MIN(date_position);
```

[dbfiddle для понимания того, как это будет работать.](https://dbfiddle.uk/nCTUoctj)

Comment: Да, результат тот что нужен. Спасибо!

Comment: @ВалерийК Если ответ подходит вам, [отметьте его как решение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)